# PHP is not returning the correct time DateTime class

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone

I have been trying to tackle this for hours and I can not seem to figure it out at all with hours of trying to find a solution so maybe someone will be of help to me

Here is my code snippet:

```
$phxtime = new \DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix');
$datetime = new \DateTime();
$datetime->setTimezone($phxtime);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s A');
```

Here is my output of above code:

```
2014-05-29 09:13:10 AM
```

It should be 4:13:10 PM (my computer time)

**How to fix this:**

Assuming you are running CentOS 6.5 64 Bit

```
yum install ntp -y

service ntpd start
```

After all of that is completed, recheck your date and everything should be in order!

Comment: this is running on a localhost?

Comment: And even if it is, is localhost configured with the correct default timezone?

Comment: No, this is running on a live production server.

Comment: well then is the server time correct?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Make sure you've the right timezone chosen and that the server isn't 1/2 way around the world.

Comment: When running date I get Thu May 29 16:29:01 UTC 2014

Comment: I got back `2014-05-29 19:32:23 PM` but I had to set mine to `America/New_York` in order to get back the time from my own timezone. Using `America/Phoenix` I get back `2014-05-29 16:33:27 PM`

Comment: [root@snip ~]# rm -rf /etc/localtime
[root@snip ~]# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix /etc/localtime
[root@snip ~]# date
Thu May 29 09:32:09 MST 2014

Comment: Okay, I've figured this out. To any one looking at this post in the future, make sure that you have NTP installed!!! yum install ntp then service ntpd start did the trick for me! Thank you all who helped!

Comment: Glad to hear it and thanks for the update. You can add your own answer if you wish.

Comment: the solution is the correct time, not install this that or the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to fix this:**

Assuming you are running CentOS 6.5 64 Bit

```
yum install ntp -y

service ntpd start
```

After all of that is completed, recheck your date and everything should be in order!